# Use overflow error as condition in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements, stack-overflow

I need to use an overflow error in Python as a condition. I.E. if the overflow error occurs then perform function b, rather than simply halting the program.

I can't find the right keywords to google if this is possible, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: add some code and error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `try/except` block:

```
try:
    raise OverflowError("Uuuups")
except OverflowError as e:
    do_some_stuff(e)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/YoungNovelSystemsoftware)